# Capture the layout and save it as image

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I have the following code below, I want to when I click on the button, the **"@+id/layout_capture"** will be captured and saved as an image .to the gallery with specified name.
I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779405/save-part-of-activity-fragment-as-image) but doesn't work with my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_capture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#AFA4BF"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/noaman_1"
    android:layout_width="89dp"
    android:layout_height="89dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"

    />
<!-- First Semister Result -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/first_semis1"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/first_semis"
    android:textAppearance="@style/first_semis"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/first_semis2"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:text="@string/first_semis"
    android:textAppearance="@style/first_semis"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    />

</LinearLayout>
  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/first_semis"
     />

   </LinearLayout>
```

> this is the screen content

[image]

> and this after capture

[image]

> **thanks for your time ❤**

Comment: you are capturing the correct view..what else do you want?

Comment: I don't know how to do it programmatically, don't know the function that does this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've copied your layout.xml file and simply added the onClick Action to the code:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/first_semis"
        android:onClick="capture"
        />
```

I used the code in your link and it does work perfectly:

Here is my MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.androidlayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    public void capture(View view){
        Bitmap photo = getBitmapFromView((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_capture));
        String savedImageURL = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                getContentResolver(),
                photo,
                "your_layout",
                "image"
        );
    }
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Bind a canvas to it
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        //Get the view's background
        Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable!=null)
            //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        // draw the view on the canvas
        view.draw(canvas);
        //return the bitmap
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
}
```

It saves the image to your gallery.

Comment: I get this error when I've tried to click the button on my smartphone https://pastebin.com/KVcHvtbt , but it works on the emulator

Comment: i've added to manifest 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
but the sae error accured !

Comment: I tried to go to app info and find out that storage permission denied. so I grant it and it works now. <3